# Not able to import database in Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to import database in `Visual Studio 2012` by following this [**link**](http://arcanecode.com/2012/08/02/sql-server-data-tools-in-visual-studio-2012importing-a-database/). I have SQL Server 2014. When I try to connect to database I am getting this error 
[image]

Also when I click on `Edit Connections` and in `Connection Properties` dialog when I click on `Test Connection` button it shows me that `Test connection succeeded` which means I dont have any problem in connection.
 But I really dont know why I am not able to `import database`?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2014, same error message that says nothing. Hope a solution will be found.

Answer (score 1):

We recently moved to SQL Server 2014 and had problems with Visual Studio integration until installing the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/tools.aspx).

In this case we were attempting to deploy a database from Visual Studio rather than importing an existing database but I think it's likely to help. The error messages we were seeing did not indicate there was a compatibility issue and we only stumbled on to the solution after trying the above.